# Strange behavior of fgetc

Tags: c++, io

I have the block of code, which I execute in some cycle and expect to get concrete result:

**The code:**

```
fseek(file, start_seek_position, SEEK_SET);
cout << "Cursor befor fgetc: " << ftell(file) << endl;
fgetc(file);
cout << "Cursor after fgetc: " << ftell(file) << endl << endl;
```

**Expections:**

```
Cursor befor fgetc: 76
Cursor after fgetc: 77

Cursor befor fgetc: 120
Cursor after fgetc: 121

Cursor befor fgetc: 170
Cursor after fgetc: 171
```

**Real result:**

```
Cursor befor fgetc: 76
Cursor after fgetc: 44

Cursor befor fgetc: 120
Cursor after fgetc: 94

Cursor befor fgetc: 170
Cursor after fgetc: 151
```

Why has this happened? I thought **fgetc** should move cursor position forward by one.

Comment: Sounds like UB. Has `file` been `fopen`ed successfully?

Comment: yes, problem, as I see with fseek

Comment: @Letfar Was the file opened in text mode or binary mode?

Comment: Time for a testcase that _reproduces the issue_.................

Comment: Please provide a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: file = fopen(file_name, "r");

Comment: Check the return value of `fgetc` for error.

Comment: Check the return value of `fseek` too.

Comment: @Letfar Since you opened the file in text mode, then the file is treated differently.  Try `"rb"` and not `"r"` for the open type.

Comment: Also, where does `start_seek_position` come from?  Because "For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be `SEEK_SET`."  See *7.21.9.2*:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: The problem is realy in open type mod. @PaulMcKenzie, Perfect, thats it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue could be that you opened the file in text mode instead of binary mode.  So instead of this:

```
file = fopen(file_name, "r"); // open as text
```

it should be this:

```
#include <cstdio>
file = fopen(file_name, "rb"); // open as binary stream, not text
```

Functions such as `ftell` and `fseek` work consistently (more to the point -- behave as expected) on files opened as a binary stream.

However, when a file is opened as a text stream (just specifying `"r"` instead of `"rb"`), there will be end-of-line and end-of-file character translations occurring, thus invariably throwing off the way that `fseek` and `ftell` work.