# Inconsistencies in file I/O

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a data type that takes ID and Record location.
The file contains around 1000 item, each contain id, first name, last name, GPA (each item total of 25 characters)
My program seeks 25 characters for each loop, takes just the ID, put the ID and the record number in the table, etc..

Then, the user inputs the id, I retrieve the item from the table based on the given id, after that I get the record number, seek the item in the file, and then read the details.

Provided the headers of the recordlocation and the arrayhashtable classes, some stuff were removed to make it shorter

```
class  RecordLocation{
public:    
    RecordLocation(int idd = -1, int rno = -1);     
    void setId(int);
    int  getId();
    void setRNo(int);
    int getRNo();
    int Hash();    
    int LinearRehash(int initial_hash_value);           
private:
    int id;
    int r_no;
};
```

/

```
    typedef RecordLocation ItemType;
    class  ArrayHashTable{  //declares a class data type

    public:
        ArrayHashTable();//Fill info with null studnets
        Error_Code RetrieveItem(ItemType&  item, bool&  found);
        Error_Code InsertItem(ItemType  item);
        Error_Code DeleteItem(ItemType  item);
        void PrintAllItems();
    private:
        ItemType info[MAX_ITEMS];
        int items;
    };
```

/
data.txt
short version

```
4609:hhhhh    hhhhh   :2:4737:ggggg    ggggg   :4:5530:rrrrr    rrrr   :4:4849:ttttttt tttttttttt:2:5563:ddddd    dddd    :2:4959:aaaa    aaaaaaa  :4:
```

/

```
void main(){    
    char buffer[26] = { '0' };
    char id_buff[5];
    int id;
    ArrayHashTable object;
    RecordLocation temp;
    ifstream input("data.txt");
    if (!input){
        cout << "Unable to open file " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int i = 0;
    int c;

//location 1    
    do{
        input.seekg(25 * i);
        input.read(id_buff, 4);
        id = convert(id_buff);

        temp.setId(id);
        temp.setRNo(i);
        object.InsertItem(temp);

        i++;

    }while (input);

//location 2        

    input.close();      
}
```

Now what is baffling is with the following statement:

```
input.seekg(25 * 3);//3 is arbitrary
    input.read(buffer, 25);
    cout << buffer << endl;
```

If it is to be placed in location 1, then it is normal output. If it is in location 2 then the output is 0. if it is both in location 1 and 2, then both output is normal.

One way to solve this is to finish the do while statement, and then close the file and open it again, perform the statement and it is all normal. But this isn't an informed solution.

What I'm basically saying is that I'm done reading the file, and after that it seems that I can't get any more information out of it. I also did not add that part to ask the user for ID (to make it simpler)

Comment: `input.seekg(25 * i)`  It is not a good idea to be using `seekg` on files opened in text mode.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482817/strange-behavior-of-fgetc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any call to `input.read` fails, your program never notices, because you never check the return code of the read method. So we have to work out what happened, rather than seeing it. Fortunately, that's not too difficult in this case but in general you will find life to be easier if you get into the habit of checking for error returns.

We know that when Location 2 is reached, `input`'s failbit is set. That must be true, because the while loop doesn't exit until `input` is false.

Since the failbit is set, neither the `seekg` nor the `read` do anything useful. The stream position is not modified,  no data is read and the buffer is unmodified.

So when the program sends `buffer` to `std::cout`, what it is sending is whatever was previously in `buffer`. If the code shown is at Location 1, then the fourth record will still be in `buffer`. Otherwise, `buffer` will contain a single '0' followed by NULs, since it was initialized to that. (0 and '0' are not the same.)

That perfectly explains the observed behaviour. Before you do the seekg, you need to clear `input`'s failbit.

---

In fact, the `while` loop is also incorrect. After the last entry is read, `input` will still be `good`, and the loop will repeat. The `read` will then fail, leaving `id` unmodified but since you don't check, the program wiil contnue, using the bogus id. Now 'input' is false and the parse fails.

What you need to do is exit the loop if either the `read` or the `seekg` fail. The explicit test of the boolean conversion of `input` is completely unnecessary and not useful because it comes too late.

Comment: Does not explain the part "if it is both in location 1 and 2, then both output is normal."

Comment: @thy: "if the code is at location 1..." reread that sentence. A failed read doesn't alter the buffer. So you just print the same buffer twice.

Comment: @ThyGamosh The whole idea of using `seekg` to get to a position in a file opened in text mode is faulty.  If the file is opened in binary mode, then that's one thing, but text mode, expect all sorts of weird things to happen when attempting to seek to a position you believe is the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/), for C++98:

> If the eofbit flag is set before the call, the function fails (sets
>   failbit and returns).

So once you have hit the end of the file, the EOF (end of file) bit is set and needs to be reset before using this function.

Note that for C++11:

> The function clears the eofbit flag, if set before the call.

So, you could try a newer compiler, or clear the eof flag using `clear`, e.g.:

```
input.clear();
```

Comment: Worked, thanks. Still, however, does not explain the part "if it is both in location 1 and 2, then both output is normal."